# bind object to more than one fieldset in a form

Tags: object, zend-framework2, bind, populate, fieldset

Having one entity but two fieldsets, I found out that just one fieldset is populated when using the use_as_base_fieldset option.

Is there a solution for that problem?

First fieldset

```
  class ProfileFieldset extends AbstractFieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
  {
      public function __construct($em)
      {
        ....
        $this->setHydrator(new Hydrator(false))
             ->setObject(new User());
         ...
      }
   ...
   }
```

Second Fieldset

```
<?php
  use \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
  use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as Hydrator;
  use User\Entity\User;

  class CredentialsFieldset extends AbstractFieldset 
    implements InputFilterProviderInterface
  {
      public function __construct($em)
      {
       .....

       $this->setHydrator(new Hydrator(false))
            ->setObject(new User());
       ....
       }
    ...
   }
```

Form

```
 use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as Hydrator;
 use User\Entity\User;

 class UserForm extends AbstractForm
 {
     public function __construct()
     {
        ....
        $this->setHydrator(new Hydrator(false))
             ->setObject(new User());
        ....

         $this->add(array(
             'type' => 'User\Form\Fieldset\ProfileFieldset',
             'options' => array(
                 'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
             )
         ));

        $this->add(array(
             'type' => 'User\Form\Fieldset\CredentialsFieldset',
             'options' => array(
                 'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
             )
         ));

         ....
      }
```

The entity itself contains properties for both fieldsets...
When binding the user entity for editing, just the last added fieldset is populated. Of course, there can be only one base fieldset ... 
Anyone having an idea, how to solve that problem?

Comment: after some more detailed investigation of the source code, I found a solution by overwriting the extract() method of zend form. 
In my opinion this is a work around.
Having the meaning of a fieldset in mind, I do expect a native populate method for all elements inside a form if a single entity is provided.

Is there sTh that I oversee? Still happy with any comments

Answer (score -1):

I think this could be done by creating a new fieldset that consists of the two fieldsets.

```
class UserForm extends AbstractForm
{
   public function __construct()
   {

     $this->add(array(
         'type' => 'User\Form\Fieldset\UserFieldset',
         'options' => array(
             'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
         )
     ));


     ....
  }
```

Then UserFieldset would become

```
<?php
namespace User\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;

class UserFieldset extends Fieldset {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('user');
        ....
        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'User\Form\Fieldset\ProfileFieldset',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'User\Form\Fieldset\CredentialsFieldset',
        ));
       .....
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
            ->setObject(new User());
        ....
    }

    ....

}
```